# How do you dynamically add a textarea to a page one time?

Tags: reactjs, forms, textarea

Does anyone know how to code this in React? Or point me to documentation?

I'm creating a forum and would like to provide the user with the ability to edit his/her comment. I've successfully built the backend but I am having trouble adding the feature to the frontend.

When the user clicks on the edit button, I'd like a textarea to open where the comment originally appears. Here's a super simple image:

[image]

I've been looking for documentation or previous posts but haven't had any luck.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using functional component.

Here's how this is usually done:

```js
const Test = () => {
    const [editing, setEditing] = useState(false);
    const [text, setText] = useState('Lorum ipsum');

    return <div>
        {editing ?
            <p>{text}</p> :
            <textarea value={text} onChange={({ target }) => setText(target.value)}></textarea>
        }
        <button onClick={() => setEditing(!editing)}>{editing ? 'Submit' : 'Edit'}</button>
    </div>;
};
```

You may test it [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/brave-greider-piny1?file=/src/App.js)